# $(AB)^-=B^-A^{-1}$ holds when $A$ is nonsingular and $B$ is singular?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, generalized-inverse

Suppose that $A$ is a nonsingular and $B$ is a singular $n\times n$ matrix. 
$B^-$ is a generalized inverse of $B$. The following statement is valid?

$(AB)^-=B^-A^{-1}$

Answer (score 4):

A generalized inverse $(AB)^-$ must satisfy the equation
$$
AB(AB)^-AB=AB.
$$

Since $A$ is nonsingular, it is enough to check
$$
B(B^-A^{-1})AB=B.
$$

But this holds since cancelling $A^{-1}$ with $A$, this amounts to $BB^-B=B$, which is the defining property of a generalized inverse.

Comment: It's very clear. Thank you so much!